# Switch statements usage and validation best way

Tags: c#, polymorphism

I have a situation where I have 2 possible classes and each inheriting the same thing except for one class is inheriting 1 more structure.

Something like:

```
Class A:    
Race
Name
Sex
Age
Location
Status
ValStat

Class B:    
Race
Name
Sex
Age
Location
Status
ValStat
Nationality
```

Both A and B are inheriting the Race, Name, Age, Sex, Status, Location and ValStat. B is defining the Nationality

Now I have a validation check based on the Class A or Class B object and I base it off an Enum meaning I have Class A associated with like Local and Class B with like International and it's based off the Location.

So, on the validaton if I check the enum and it's Local then I run the local validation check and if Internional then I base it off a validation. In some of the validations they are the same like associated with Age or Sex. Meaning whether local or International they are still validated.

Right now, I have switch statements.

So I check the Status in the switch and then I check the enum then perform the validation off the enum.

```
switch (Status)
{
    case Citizen:

         switch (A.Location)
         {

              case West:

                   do common validation using the A object
                   Update the A object ValStat
              break;

              case East:

                  do common validation using the B object
                  do international validation
                  Update the B object ValStat
              break; 
         }
         break;

    case Alien:

         switch (A.Location)
         {

              case West:

                   do alien confirmation using the A object
                   Update the A object ValStat
              break;

              case East:

                  do alien confirmation using the B object 
                  do internation validation
                  Update the B object ValStat
              break; 
         }
         break;

}
```

Now, from a readability standpoint I do not see it that bad but from a maintenance/update standpoint if I have to add something in the common validation they I need to do it in 2 places. Or if I need to change the Update for the ValStat then I need to do it in 4.

If there another or better way to do something like this?

Comment: Have you looked at the strategy pattern?

Comment: Sounds like a job for an abstract class

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 4):

You need to take a look at the [strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    //All your properties
    public virtual Boolean Validate()
    {
        //Common Validation code
    }
}

public class A : BaseClass
{
    public override Boolean Validate()
    {
         return AValidation || base.Validate();
    }
}

//Same for B
```

Usage

```
BaseClass base = new A or B
base.Validate();
```

It might be worth breaking out the validation code to help with [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) and [it is usually better to prefer composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    readonly Validator _validator;
    protected BaseClass(Validator validator){_validator = validator;}
    public Boolean Validate()
    {
        return _validator.Validate();
    }
}
```

Then, you can abstract the differences in validation away also.

Comment: Question...how is this even remotely even better for readability. It does not appear as though it would. With the switches you sacrifice maintenance over readability. With the use of the abstract class you sacrifice readibility over maintenance. And it involves more construction to boot. So, I question what is the value of an abstract class when you end up sacrificing?

Comment: By the way, I cannot change the "public class A" or the "public class B". They are used by other parts of the system. This is used in a WCF Service for my part and I'm reusing already developed artifacts, tested and usaged artifacts. Even changing that would really put into question the value-add of an abstract class for this because of the changes that needs to be constructed in addition to the regression testing which would have to be done (it makes sense.)

Are there any other possibilities?

Comment: Actually, you gain maintainability and readability. Yes, if you want to know the details you will need to drill down, but your high level API reads clean. I am using abstract names, but names make a difference...but that is true with everything. I question you on whether you really think procedural code is readable.

Comment: And, if you are trying to gain maintainability and readability and cannot change the A or B, then wrap them up. After that, it is trivial.

Comment: "I question you on whether you really think procedural code is readable." That's subjective because I really do not think the abstract class gains the readability. (That is subjective as well.) I think the switches do. But in a sense you confirm the aspect of readability or lack thereof when you stated "...want to know the details you will need to drill down.." Really? (rhetorical) For readability I should not really have to drill down; it should be a quick observation.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "...then wrap them up." Can you explain? I'm really starting to wonder...for something so relatively small I really question if the implementation of the abstract class is a value-add with the amount of effort associated. I'm trying to find compelling pro's and con's